# Highly incorrect predictions by any architecture retrained on any new classes of images using tensorflow hub retraining script

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm using the [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) for retraining on flower images available [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#2). My output  is     
`INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/_retrain_checkpoint
INFO:tensorflow:Final test accuracy = 92.5% (N=362)
INFO:tensorflow:Save final result to : tf_files/retrained_graph.pb`
So, 92.5% accuracy with Inception V3 and the tfhub_module is [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1)
But when I'm predicting the image with

```
python -m scripts.label_image \
    --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
    --image=tf_files/flower_photos/roses/568715474_bdb64ccc32.jpg \
    --input_height=299 \
    --input_width=299 \
    --input_layer='Placeholder
```

My output is

```
Evaluation time (1-image): 3.639s         
daisy (score=0.54625)  
tulips (score=0.18089)  
roses (score=0.17955)  
dandelion (score=0.06436)  
sunflowers (score=0.02894)
```

For a perfect rose, it's predicting as daisy. This is happening for almost all images in this flower dataset and also another dataset. There's another retraining script by [Google Codelabs](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py) . When I'm using the same flower dataset for retraining using this script, I'm getting ~93% accuracy and it's also predicting correctly.

```
Evaluation time (1-image): 1.857s
roses (score=0.99969)
tulips (score=0.00030)
sunflowers (score=0.00001)
daisy (score=0.00000)
dandelion (score=0.00000)
```

So, what's the difference between these two scripts and why is the 1st script predicting the images incorrectly despite showing very high final test accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion and the solution are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/81).

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say what the exact error might be, but I'm certain it's not the retrain code. It's most likely the test code you're using. The test code from the tutorial depends on a labels.txt file which is used to match a vector with their corresponding label.

Each time you run the retrain.py, the labels.txt might become different, and I've the feeling that in this case, the labels if labels.txt are in a wrong order. Not sure if this is the solution, just a gut feeling.